# Assign an Int from a Double Pointer (Pointer to Pointer) in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am somewhat confused on how to assign assign an Int from a pointer to pointer, all the logic of referencing and dereferencing pointers I still don't quite get.

My code:

```
int c (char **args)
{
  int steps=0;

  steps=args[1]; //what I am generally trying to do
}
```

In addition, a heads up for way to convert the `args` array into an int would also be superb.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks beforehand.

Comment: Use [atoi](https://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) or sscanf. `args[1]` is a pointer to a textual representation of a number, as in "123", which needs to be parsed. `sscanf` returns the number of successfully parsed items. In your case it should be 1; 0 indicates that the string was not a number.

Comment: Perhaps you should have `steps = atoi(args[1])` because `args` is being treated as an array of pointers. The `char **args` can also be defined as `char *args[]`

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! Everything works now

Comment: By the way, here as always a pointer contains the address of an object of the type "with one asterisk less": here `args` points to an object of type `char *`, i.e. <pointer to `char`>. There may or may not follow more objects of that type in memory, i.e. if `args[0]` is a valid pointer to `char`,  `args[1]` may or may not exist, and if it exists, may or may not be the null pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int c(char **args)
{
   int steps = atoi(args[1]);
}
```

Convert string to integer using `atoi`

Comment: just be aware that atoi is not safe to use, since it doesn't handle invalid input! Using instead strtol is safer.